# Specifying dump directory in mongod.cfg file

Tags: mongodb, directory, config, dump, mongodump

All,

Is there a system wide setting to specify the dump folder in MongoDB? I went [**through this link**](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/configuration-options/) and couldn't find any.

Basically, I want **C:\MongoDB\dump** to be the folder where all backups are created. Currently, a dump folder is created in the folder mongodump is executed in or one has to specify a folder explicitly using --out parameter as a part of mongodump.

Instead, wherever I may execute mongodump from, I want the dumps to be always created in **C:\MongoDB\dump**

Thanks,
rgn

Answer (score 0):

You can use [mongodump](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/program/mongodump/)

```
mongodump --host mongodb1.example.net --port 37017 --username user --password "pass" --out /opt/backup/mongodump-2011-10-24
```

Answer (score 0):

If you do not specify the `--out` paramater to the `mongodump`, it will create a `dump` directory in the current directory to store the database dump.

You can set a system level parameter for the base directory for all of your dumps. However, for every `mongodump` you take you will have to pass the --out parameter to uniquely identify that dump.

Failing to do so will overwrite the existing dumps within your base dump directory